# 「ぺったん」→「ぺったら」 – A conjugation of an onomatopoeic adverb?

Tags: conjugations, adverbs, onomatopoeia

The sentence in question (from [here (page 14)](http://life.ou.edu/stories/sarukani.html)):

> ぺったんペったら牛の糞が、やって来ました。

What does the 〜ら conjugation (?) of the second ぺったん mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a rare or unique onomatopoeia, not a kind of conjugation. You wouldn't see this outside of a few fairy tales or children's songs. I think worrying about this is like worrying about every single weird expression in Mother Goose.

Still, although this may be a far-fetched analysis, this somewhat sounds like [えっちらおっちら](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89), and I vaguely feel the nuance of "all the way" in this ら.